# Copy rows after loop

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

after my last question I'm facing a problem with copying rows.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ws1');
  var startRow = 4;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numRows = lastRow  - startRow + 1;
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataSetValues = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastCol).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
    let fVal =  dataSetValues[i][5];   
    let gVal = dataSetValues[i][6];
    let sum = +fVal + +gVal;
        
    if (sum > 115) {  
      let row = dataSetValues[i];
    }
  }
```

**What do I expect?**

I wish set which columns to copy

I edited the code like this

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ws1');
  var startRow = 4;
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numRows = lastRow  - startRow + 1;
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataSetValues = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastCol).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
```

> ```
>     let aVal =  dataSetValues[i][0];
>     let bVal =  dataSetValues[i][1]; // + other columns
> ```

```
    let fVal =  dataSetValues[i][5];   
    let gVal = dataSetValues[i][6];
    let sum = +fVal + +gVal;
        
    if (sum > 115) {  
      let row = dataSetValues[i];
```

> ```
>   var ssDest = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ws2');
>   var rngDest = ssDest.getRange(ssDest.getLastRow()+1,1);
>
>   //start copy
>   rngDest.setValues(row)
> ```

```
    }
  }
```

I get this error

**The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues**

Thanks

Comment: Try `rngDest.setValues([row])`

Comment: There is also a few `copyTo` and `copyValuesToRange` methods that might be a better fit to your needs. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: Tried with rngDest.setValues([row]); but "The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range". I would like the column A to column A, the B to B etc

Comment: The dimension of `row` is [1 x lastCol], and the dimension of `rngDest` is [1 x 1]. That's why the number of columns does not match. First, you have to use all four arguments to get a [1 x lastCol] range, namely, `ssDest.getRange(ssDest.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, lastCol)`. Then set the values using `rngDest.setValues([row])`.

Comment: I don't know if is a problem of columns, In the source sheet I have more columns but to dest I should have fewer columns. I have this error  Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your script just needs a few changes made to it:

**1. It is important to note that the `setValues()` method accepts as parameter a two dimensional array in the form of `Object[][]`.**

You are simply passing it a one-dimensional array, hence the `The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues` error you are receiving.

In order to fix this, you will have to transform `row` into a 2 dimensional array and making the following changes

**From**

```
rngDest.setValues(row)
```

**To**

```
rngDest.setValues([row])
```

**2. You will have to specify exactly the number of rows and the number of columns expected in the destination range.**

After making the change above, you will end up running into a `The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range` error which is again expected. This is due to the fact that the `getRange` method will also need the number of rows and the number of columns such that when using `setValues` it will know exactly the structure of the data to set.

If you take a look at the `getRange` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns):

> ```
> getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
> ```
>
> Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates with the given number of rows and columns.

In order to fix this, a simple change has to be made in order to indicate exactly the number of rows and the number of columns:

**From**

```
var rngDest = ssDest.getRange(ssDest.getLastRow()+1,1)
```

**To**

```
var rngDest = ssDest.getRange(ssDest.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, row.length);
```

As you can see, the number of rows here is 1 (as you are copying the data one row at a time) and the number of columns is equal to `row.length` (as the `row` variable has all the values corresponding to one row at a time).

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Range Class - setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues);
- [Apps Script Sheet Class - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Apps Script Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting).

Comment: Hi , my last answer is gone. Anyway thank you, it works perfectly. I would like to ask if it is possible to add the timestamp on each copied row.

Comment: I am glad to hear this! Yes, that is possible. You might want to check this article [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates) and afterwards depending on where exactly you want to place the timestamp, you will have to use the `getRange` and `setValue` methods.

Comment: Hi, yestarday I asked a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868397/copy-and-add-timestamp. 
Thanks again