# Add timestamp with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**MY GOAL**

Using the following code I would like to add a timestamp in column A

```
  for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
    let aVal = dataSetValues[i][0];    
    let bVal = dataSetValues[i][1];    
    let cVal = dataSetValues[i][2];
    let dVal = dataSetValues[i][3];
    let fVal = dataSetValues[i][5];  
    let gVal = dataSetValues[i][6];
    let hVal = dataSetValues[i][7];
    // + other columns

    let sum = +fVal + +gVal;
        
    if (sum > 115) {          
      let row = dataSetValues[i];          
      var rngDest = dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow() + 1, 6, 1, row.length);          
      rngDest.setValues([row]);    
    }
  }
```

**MY CURRENT CODE**

```
 var i = spreadsheet.getActiveCell();
   if(i.getColumn() == 6) {          
      var timestamp = i.offset(0, -5);          
      if( timestamp.getValue() === '' )            
        timestamp.setValue(new Date());      
      }
   }
```

**PROBLEM**

The timestamp doesn't appear, it works if I type manually in column F.
I'd like to avoid using OnEdit script, it's possible to do it directly while copying?

**UPDATE**

I added full main code. I need a timestamp in column A.
I would like to avoid using onedit because ws2 is a sheet where I will add other data and therefore it will be editable.

Comment: What is the value inside of column F?

Comment: It should be alphanumeric but if i try manually, it works both with numbers and with text

Comment: What is the log of `onEdit`?

Comment: No log and no error, the timestamp simply doesn't appear. If I cancel/rewrite the value in colum A, timestamp works.

Comment: Rewrite? What are you talking about? Also, what is the first code in your question. Please explain in details you steps of testing `onEdit`.

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet

Comment: You should add trhe solution as an an answer rather than editing your question @Zimox

Answer (score 0):

I **solved** with

```
dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow(),1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```